# extracting fixed effects and standard errors from several lme objects in R

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is any smart way to automatically extract several different fixed effects (as well as their standar errors) from a series of lme objects. I would like to create something like a latex table from these outputs so that the results can be compared side by side. Something like the functionality of the apsrtable package. Thanks! Antonio.

Comment: Since you know how to extract the coefficients themselves, next you'll need to familiarize yourself with the `xtable` package and/or the `latex` function in `Hmisc`. Organize the model information the way you like in a data frame and then use either of these tools to construct a latex table. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, feel free to ask another question, but be sure to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, I am already quite familiar with xtable package as well as how to extract these lme coefficients. The whole point of my post is exactly how to avoid reinvent the wheels by  learning how people dealt with my question. I can actually do it by myself, but by using a somewhat convoluted solution, which I am sure is far from best. Antonio.

Comment: It's beginning to sound like your question is about whether there exists a package/functions that does this for you for lme objects. That is not at all what your question title+body say. You might consider editing your question to reflect this discrepancy. If you want suggestions for how to improve your current solution, you'll have to actually provide some code.

Comment: OK. What would be a more informative title? "How to automatically create a table with coefficients from several lme objects"?

Comment: So far I haven't thought of any alternatives besides (1) hacking one of the existing packages (apsrtable, mtable-lme4, or the guts of my coefplot2 function) or (2) writing your own.  Don't know if I will have time to do any of the above ... good question, though, and a functionality that should be available.

Comment: I see this thread is quite old, but I believe the `stargazer` package can do this now.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
library(nlme)
## from ?lme:
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont) # random is ~ age
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
L <- list(A=fm1,B=fm2)
lapply(L, function(x) summary(x)$tTable)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: I am familiar with this functionality but I was wondering how to get create something like a latex table from the output so that the results can be compared side by side. Something like the apsrtable package does for other packages. Best, Antonio.

Comment: What if you wanted to extract random effects?

Comment: `lapply(L, ranef)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
fm.lmer <- lmer(formula, data=Data)
fm.Means <- data.frame("Mean"=fixef(fm.lmer)[-1])
fm.SEs <- data.frame("SEM"=sqrt(diag(vcov(fm.lmer)))[-1])
fm.MeansSEs <- data.frame("Entry"=gsub('Entry', '', rownames(fm.Means), 
                          fixed = TRUE),"Mean"=fm.Means, "SEM"=fm.SEs)
```

Another choice could be [mtable-lme4](http://www.r-bloggers.com/code-latex-tables-for-lme4-models/)  function.

Comment: Thanks but the mtable-lme4 doesn't work for objects of signature "lme" just "mer". Anyway, this is a nice code but doesn't address the question of creating a table displaying information from several different models.  Best, Antonio.

Answer (score 0):

See [Alan Munn's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z342N.png) answer to my same kin of question on tex.stackexchange.com.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\title{Side-by-side xtables}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
First some R code to create some data.
<<>>=
myData <- matrix(c(19,89,23,23,74,44,16,39,67),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(myData) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(myData) <- c("1","2","3")
myData2 <- myData * 2
@

Now we place the data in two side-by-side tables:

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
print(xtable(myData),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The first table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
print(xtable(myData2),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData2)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The second table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I think this is still not what the OP wants -- it doesn't automatically extract and combine the information from several models with possibly differing/overlapping sets of parameters ...

Comment: @BenBolker: You right. But this idea can be used to accomplish the requirement.

Comment: @MYaseen208: where is your new answer? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: I don't see how this can be directly helpful to my original question. I would like to create a matrix our dataframe in which each column or pair of columns are the results of a lme model (coefs and errors). That's it. From there it is trivial to make a table in latex or sweave. Best, Antonio.